# "PyPDF2 Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream ..." when merging and writing PDFs that individually all have EOF?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Merging a set of PDFs (a personal profile record + a variable amount of PDF image scans) in a loop like...

```py
def merge_scans_to_record(record_filename: str, scans_data_paths: typing.List[str]):
    record_path = os.path.join(RECORD_PATH, record_filename)
    print(f"Processing {record_filename}, path {record_path}")
    pdf_merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    pdf_merger.append(str(record_path))
    # go through each scan path for this person
    for scan_path in scans_data_path:
        pdf_merger.append(str(scan_path))
    # write this new extended PDF to new location
    OUTFILE = os.path.join(OUTPUT_HOME, f"{pat_record_filename.split('.')[0]}.appended.pdf")
    assert not os.path.isfile(OUTFILE), f"ERROR: File {OUTFILE} already exists"
    pdf_merger.write(OUTFILE)
    pdf_merger.close()
```

...and getting error message...

> PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte 0x9cd37

...for one (so far) of the sets of PDFs I'm trying to merge at the point where I am trying to actually write the merged pdf (ie. at the line `pdf_merger.write(OUTFILE)`).

Checking the last few bytes in each of the PDFs in question like...

```py
def print_pdf_contents(filepath):
    print(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as fd:
        # looking at the last bytes
        pprint.pprint(fd.readlines()[-3:])
        # just checking that PyPDF2 can open and read the PDFs
        doc = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fd)
        print(f"Total pages: {doc.getNumPages()}")
        for pg in range(0, doc.getNumPages()):  # range end is exclusive, but OK b/c pgs are indexed from 0
            page_strings = doc.getPage(pg).extractText().split('\n')
            print(page_strings)
    print('\n\n\n\n\n')
```

and seeing output like

> [b'startxref\n', b'63091\n', b'%%EOF\n']

for each. **Note they do all *end* with `%%EOF\n`** (so unfortunately this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66058416/8236733) does not address the issue) and **I can manually open them all in a PDF viewer** (Windows Edge browser). **IDK if there is a difference between EOF and "endstream" markers**.
I am doing this with multiple sets of PDFs and this is the first time I am running into this error.

Anyone with more experience w/ in the internals of PDFs or w/ PyPDF2 know what could be going on here or have other debugging suggestions?

---

**UPDATE**:
Using a hex editor and examining the position 0x9cd37 for all the PDFs involved in the merge that actually had bytes that went up to that position, I found the following byte values (here represented as lists of three to include the 2 preceding bytes before position 0x9cd37 in each file just in case):

```
[0x84, 0x0a, 0xa9], 
[0xe9, 0x25, 0x10], 
[0x1a, 0x12, 0x6d]
```

Anyone know if these characters could be causing issues and how?

Comment: *"IDK if there is a difference between EOF and "endstream" markers"* - they are different. The `%%EOF` ends a document (or document revision). `endstream` ends a stream object in a document. *"I can manually open them all in a PDF viewer"* - that does not mean a lot. Most pdf viewers repair or ignore a lot of errors under the hood, more or less successfully, without telling the user. Thus, it simply looks like the pdf has an internal error which common viewers ignore. Please share the pdf in question for a more detailed analysis.

Comment: @mkl Interesting info. Unfortunately can't share the document as they contain people's personal information, but could share debugging findings in the post (if I understand the output enough -- ie. printing bytes -- to be sure there is no PII in them) if given any suggestions on some things to check for.

Comment: Well, you could inspect the file around the position mentioned in the error message, `at byte 0x9cd37`.

Comment: @mkl I see. Some questions: 1) It appears that the error is happening during the `pdf_merger.write()` operation. How do I read the bytes of the file it is *failing* to be created? Is the empty file that get produced going to be useful to read? 2) If it's the existing PDFs that should be examined, I would just do something like open the files in `rb` mode and then `my_file_descriptor.read(X)` where X = the hex `0x9cd37` converted to decimal form, right?

Comment: Unless the error message is misleading, the error position should be in the read pdf (read just in time, not ahead of time). And simply use a hex viewer (best in a side-by-side hex/text view) to inspect the data around that offset.

Comment: @mkl Just to confirm I'm not doing this wrong: I downloaded HxD hex editor and opened all of the PDFs and, in each, use Search>Find to look for Hex-value "9cd37", but can find nothing in any of the files. Am I doing it wrong else what could this inform about the possible nature of the problem?

Comment: Do not search for the *value* 9cd37 but scroll to the *position* 9cd37.

Comment: Please search backwards from that position to the previous *n **0 obj*** (where *n* is a number) and post from there until ***stream*** including last and first offset of that section. Then go to the next *m **0 obj*** (where *m* is a number) and post until there from the previous ***endstream***.