# Merge multiple pdf files into single txt file

Tags: python, loops, pdf, merge, pypdf

I want to `loop` through a directory of `.pdf` files and merge all of them into a single `.txt` file. So far I have this code, but it won't write anything into `file.txt`. I get the following error:

```
raise PdfReadError("EOF marker not found")
PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found
```

Here's the code:

```py
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

for filename in os.listdir("path"):
    path = os.path.join("path/", filename)
    print(path)
    with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for page_num in range(PdfFileReader(path, strict=False).numPages):
            print('Página: {0}'.format(page_num))
            pageObj = PdfFileReader(path).getPage(page_num)
            
            try:
                txt = pageObj.extractText()
            except:
                pass
            else:
                file.write('Page{0}\n'.format(page_num+1))
                file.write(txt)
        file.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EOF marker not found while use PyPDF2 merge pdf file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390608/eof-marker-not-found-while-use-pypdf2-merge-pdf-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

```py
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import SimpleTextExtraction
from pathlib import Path

def get_text_from_pdf(p: Path) -> str:
   l: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
   with open(p, "rb") as fh:
       PDF.loads(fh, [l])
   return "".join([(v+"\n") for k,v in l.get_text().items()])
```

Now you can simply call this for every file in the directory.

Comment: If it works, you can upvote my answer. Or even mark my answer as the accepted answer :-)